# numpy.asarray leaves inner dimensions uncoverted

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have written a small piece of code to read some numbers from a file into an array.

```
import numpy as np

def read_blocks(filename):

    with open(filename) as f:

        array = []

        for line in f:

            if not line.strip():

                array.append([])
                next(f)

            else:array[-1].append([float(x) for x in line.split()])

        array = np.asarray(array)

    return array
```

The above code works as expected for a test file that I created with some numbers. Something like

```
1 2 3
4 5 6

7 8 9
10 11 12
```

creates a (2,1,3) numpy.ndarray. But when I try a file with lots of rows (8939 in my case), numpy.asarray is leaving the inner lists as it is and not converting them to arrays i.e., I get a numpy.ndarray with a shape of (2,) and the inner elements are all still lists. Has anyone else ever faced this issue with numpy.asarray?

Appreciate any help I can get!

Comment: Have you tried [numpy.genfromtxt()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html)?? Something like, `with open(fpath) as f: a = numpy.genfromtxt(f.read())`

Comment: Seems like - If it works with a file of four lines, it should work with a file of x lines.

Comment: I usually use numpy.genfromtxt(), but I want to import the file into an ndarray changing dimension based on the 2 empty lines in between. I did not find this feature in numpy.genfromtxt(), so decided to write it myself. I know it should work with any number of lines if it works with a smaller file. This is what makes it so frustrating. I don't understand why its happening.

Comment: My guess is the array is `dtype` object, and that the elements are lists of differing size.  You create a nested list.  To convert that to a multidimensional numeric array, all sublists have to have a consistent length.

Comment: All the elements are lists of same size. I've gone through the file and its 8939 rows and 4 columns all the way through, with 2 empty lines in between as mentioned in the previous comment.

Comment: Should the example data result in an array of shape (4,3)?

Comment: The example data is supposed to have first 2 lines empty in order for the code to work. I couldn't figure out how to do that while creating the post and so it should create an array of shape (2,1,3), which it does.

Comment: @hpaulj is right. The number of lists in the 3rd dimension are different and that's why they were left untouched. I'll work out some different code to get them in different arrays. Thank you for the insight.